# Photoshop and Adobe Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

What is the difference between "Photoshop" and "Adobe Photoshop"?
Please I need help .

Comment: In what context? One can be a verb, the other is a graphics app.

Comment: `Adobe` is the name of the company that makes `Photoshop`. When you hear people use the word `Photoshop`, it refers to that application. There is also `Photoshop Elements`, or at least there used to be, and that is like a lite version of `Photoshop`... Or again, it used to be (as far as I know). Not sure if they perhaps changed its direction or something, but I'm pretty sure it was like a stripped down PS but geared for the "casual" user who didn't need all the bells and whistles. Possibly cheaper too.

Comment: Adobe Photoshop is a raster graphics editor developed and published by Adobe Inc. for Windows and macOS. Read all the history from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop)

Comment: There is no "Photoshop" without "Adobe" `:)`

Comment: Would there be Adobe without Photoshop?

Comment: Probably not. `:)`

Answer (score 4):

The word "Adobe"?

That word is the company owner of the product Photoshop.

The same as "*Ford*" Mustang. "*Microsoft*" Windows, "*Apple*" iPhone, "*MacDonald*" BigMac.

---

But as it is the most recognizable program of its type, many people use the word as a... *verb*.

"Let's do some Photoshopping on the image", "Let's Photoshop this" Meaning that they want to retouch an image.